# 3D Array value assignment ruins the structure of array

Tags: r, matrix

Here is how to reproduce my problem. I want to create a 3D array

```
> g=array(0,dim=c(3,31,31))
> dim(g)
[1] 3 31 31
> dim(g[1,,])
[1] 31 31
```

This is x with dimension 31 by 31

```
> dim(x)
[1] 31 31
> x
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
1  NA  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2   0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
3   2  1 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
4   0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   0  0  0  0  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
7   0  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
16  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
17  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 NA  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
21  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
22  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
23  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
24  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
25  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0
26  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0
27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  0  1  0  0
28  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0
29  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 NA  0  0
30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0
31  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA
```

when I try to assign x to the first 'section' of g using

```
> g[1,,] = x
```

The array structure of g is totally changed, as now it becomes:

```
> dim(g)
NULL
> head(g)
[[1]]
[1] NA  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1]  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0

[[5]]
[1] 0

[[6]]
[1] 0
```

This is totally different from what I expected, I am just trying to put a matrix to g[1,,] and dim(g) should still be 3 by 31 by 31, am I wrong? where did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you create "x"?

Comment: Start with a simple example and see if you can get it to work. e.g. `g <- array(0,dim=c(3,3,3)); x <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3); g[,,1] <- x` - I'm guessing your `x` isn't actually a matrix/array but something else. Try `x <- as.matrix(x)` first.

Comment: I tried x <- as.matrix(x) and it worked out well. And initially the class(x) = 'data.frame', I feel like an idiot now. Thanks and hope you wrote a answer rather than a comment so I can choose it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pascal's comments below I've amended my answer, though I've left the dimensionality changed to 31x31x3 for perhaps easier understanding.  The problem is the way that the data are converted from your data.frame object before storing in your array.  I think by converting first to a matrix you should get what you're looking for:

```
g <- array(0,dim=c(31,31,3))
m <- matrix(1, 31, 31)
x <- as.data.frame(m)

##  Storing x as it is will result in g becoming a list...
#g[,,1] <- x

##  Converting the data.frame to a matrix will result in 
##    g remaining an array:
g[,,1] <- as.matrix(x)
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. You are showing to the OP what he already knows. The OP's problem is more what is the class of the object "x", as mentioned by thelatemail.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the class of `x` at all.  It's just a matrix and his assignment throws no error. The dimensions of his array are what is causing him to think his array structure is "changed."  He is assigning a 31x31 matrix to the first rows of a 3x31 matrix across 31 "slices" of the third dimension.  This isn't "wrong" but it doesn't appear to be right because when he prints the array R will always take the first two dimensions and print them as a matrix before repeating that across subsequent dimensions.  So no, I disagree that I'm showing the OP what he already knows.

Comment: The OP said above that his "x" was of class "data.frame".

Comment: Ah, you're correct, and I apologize for my initial comment.  I've amended my answer above to reflect your insight, though I see the OP already solved this in his comments.  Shall I delete this then?